# Is there any bouldering (climbing) guide for Khon Kaen (Thailand)?

Tags: thailand, guidebooks, climbing

We want to visit Khon Kaen to go bouldering, but I couldn't find any bouldering guides.

I would like to have a guidebook or some information online to prepare the trip.

Answer (score 2):

[Mountain Project](https://www.mountainproject.com/v/khon-kaen/112803120) has 60+ problems listed for Khon Kaen.  [The Crag](https://www.thecrag.com/climbing/thailand/area/838778526) also has a bit of information.  Both suggest contacting the [Khon Kaen Climbing Club](https://www.facebook.com/khonkaenclimbingclub/) on Facebook for more information.